# I want to add "Edit" functionality. When I click Edit, it adds a duplicate record instead of editing

Tags: java

This is my Operations.java, products.Java class and Products.jsp file:

In which I implemented the Add and Edit functionality. The add button is working fine but the edit button is adding a duplicate record instead of editing the record. Please tell me how do I implement edit function in my program ?

```
package metier;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Operation {

private ArrayList<Produit> produits = new ArrayList<Produit>();

public ArrayList<Produit> getProduits() {
    return produits;
}

public void setProduits(ArrayList<Produit> produits) {
    this.produits = produits;
}

public void add(Produit p){
    produits.add(p);
}

public void remove(Long id){
    for(Produit p:produits){
        if(p.getId()==id){ //equals
            produits.remove(p);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void edit(Long id){
    for(Produit p:produits){
        if(p.getId()==id){
            p.getId();
            p.getName();
            p.getContactno();
            p.getSPS();
            produits.add(p);

            break;
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList getAll(){
    return produits;
}
```

}

```
package metier;

public class Produit {

private Long id;
private String name, address, contactNo, SparePartsService;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getContactno() {
    return contactNo;
}
public void setContactno(String contactNo) {
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
}
public String getSPS() {
    return SparePartsService;
}
public void setSPS(String SparePartsService) {
    this.SparePartsService = SparePartsService;
}
public Produit() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Produit(String name, String address, String contactNo, String SparePartsService) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
    this.SparePartsService = SparePartsService;
}
public Produit(Long id, String name, String address, String contactNo, String SparePartsService) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
    this.SparePartsService = SparePartsService;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return id + " - " + name + " - " + address + " - " + contactNo + " - " + SparePartsService + " .";
}

public void Show(){
    System.out.println(toString());
}
```

}

```
<%@ page import="web.ProduitBeans"%>
<%@ page import="metier.Produit"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Getiteasy.Net</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    ProduitBeans produits;
if(request.getAttribute("modele") != null){
    produits = (ProduitBeans) request.getAttribute("modele");
}else{
    produits = new ProduitBeans();
}
%>
<h3>Tutorial MVC(Model, View, Controller)</h3>
<h5>Ajouter un nouveau produit</h5>

<form action="prodserv" method="post">
    <table border="1" width="45%">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact No.</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="contactNo"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Spare Parts Service(Yes/No)</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="SparePartsService"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Valider"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<table border="1" width="60%">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Contact No.</th>
        <th>Spare Parts Service</th>
        <th>Option</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        Iterator<Produit> list = produits.getListe().iterator();
        while(list.hasNext()){
            Produit p = list.next();
    %>
    <tr>
        <td><%=p.getId() %></td>
        <td><%=p.getName() %></td>
        <td><%=p.getAddress() %></td>
        <td><%=p.getContactno() %></td>
        <td><%=p.getSPS() %></td>
        <td>
            <form action="prodserv" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=p.getId() %>" >
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="supprimer" >
                <input type="submit" value="supprimer"/>    
            </form>
                <form action="prodserv" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=p.getId() %>" >
                <input type="hidden" name="editaction" value="Edit" >
                <input type="submit" value="Edit"/>     
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
```

Comment: When debugging a problem you need to read your code and actually understand what it's doing. Look at the `edit` method as Martek says. Read each line. You iterate, throw away the results of the getter methods, and add another reference to the object you're editing.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want your edit method to do? Look at your edit method. If you find a product with the ID you are just calling the getter methods and you are doing nothing with the data. After that you are just adding the same object again to your list. You need to define what data you want to edit and then overwrite the data with a setter method. And don't add the object again to your list.

Comment: I want to edit the values by pressing the edit button and providing new values !

Comment: you could change your edit method to something like this:

just change the getter methods do setter methods -> `setID("value")` and get rid of this line `produits.add(p);`

Comment: what do you mean by: just change the getter methods do setter methods ??

Comment: Can you provide the correct code for edit function ?>

Comment: i think it is always better to get to the solution by yourself.

you need to understand where the new data comes from, where it is stored and how to access the data. then you just need to overwrite the old with the new data of the product with the specified ID.

if you want a code example, then look at "MrMe TumbsUp" solution. it gives you all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Working with an ArrayList for this purpose is very unefficiant, you will be looping your list many many times which will take longer and longer as your list is growing. Better make use of a Map, it "maps" a key to a value so you can call that value directly by the predefined key and don't have to loop the whole list.

### In your Operation class:

- change the `ArrayList<Produit> produits ...` to `Map<Long,Produit> = new HashMap<>()`
  (Also I would recommand you making it static, to ensure the you keep the same list across the board)
- Add a `private static Long idCounter=0L`

Then when you **Add** a new Produit, do:

```
public void add(Produit p){
    idCounter++;
    p.setId(idCounter);
    produits.put(idCounter,p);
}
```

**Remove**:

```
public void remove(Produit p){
    produits.remove(p.getId());
    }
```

*Note.*
No `idcounter--;` here because you don't know if it is the last one in your map, So baicly you will be skipping some id's if you removed alot of elements.
The id of the Produit that you want to remove has to be set on the p parameter.

**Edit**:

```
public void edit(Produit p){
   produits.put(p.getId(),p);
}
```

*Note.*
The ID of the Produit that you want to remove has to be set on the p parameter.

**getAll**:

```
public Collection<Produit> getAll(){
    produits.values();
}
```

### In your JSP page:

You have to somehow tell your controller what action it has to do. You can do this by using an Action parameter.
You have done this for one case (Delete (=supprimer FR)).

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="supprimer" >
```

To edit you must do it again, so change:

```
<input type="hidden" name="editaction" value="Edit" >
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="Edit" >
```

*Note.* "name"-tag is the name of the parameter like number is the name of the variable `Int number`.

### In your Controller (servlet):

**your:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)             throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (req.getParameter("action") != null) {
        op.remove(Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id")));
    } 
    else {          // Recuprer les information
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String address = req.getParameter("address");
        String contactNo = req.getParameter("contactNo");
        String SparePartsService = req.getParameter("SparePartsService");
        op.add(new Produit(1L, name, address, contactNo,SparePartsService));
    }
```

In the "else"-clause of you if-satement that checks if action-parameter is null, you only have the functionality to add a Produit.

**you must add:**

```
 if(req.getParameter("action").equals("Add")){
                    String name = req.getParameter("name");
            String address = req.getParameter("address");
            String contactNo = req.getParameter("contactNo");
            String SparePartsService = req.getParameter("SparePartsService");
            op.add(new Produit(1L, name, address, contactNo,SparePartsService));
}else if (req.getParameter("action").equals("Edit")){
                    String name = req.getParameter("name");
            String address = req.getParameter("address");
            String contactNo = req.getParameter("contactNo");
            String SparePartsService = req.getParameter("SparePartsService");
                    Long id = Long.ParseLong(req.getParameter("id"));
            op.edit(new Produit(id, name, address, contactNo,SparePartsService));
}
```

**Result:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)             throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (req.getParameter("action") != null) {
        op.remove(Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id")));
    } 
 // Recuprer les information
    else if(req.getParameter("action").equals("Add")){
            String name = req.getParameter("name");
            String address = req.getParameter("address");
            String contactNo = req.getParameter("contactNo");
            String SparePartsService = req.getParameter("SparePartsService");

            op.add(new Produit(1L, name, address, contactNo,SparePartsService));

    }else if (req.getParameter("action").equals("Edit")){
            String name = req.getParameter("name");
            String address = req.getParameter("address");
            String contactNo = req.getParameter("contactNo");
            String SparePartsService = req.getParameter("SparePartsService");
            Long id = Long.ParseLong(req.getParameter("id"));

            op.edit(new Produit(id, name, address, contactNo,SparePartsService));
    }
}
```

*Note.* You must add a new "else if"-clause for every possible action-parameter value that you want to implement.

I advise you to put the functionality that is within these if-clauses in a seperate private function, if not your `doPost(...)` function will get very long.
Or even better take a look at the Command-patern.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I want to edit the record by pressing edit button and providing new values !

Comment: Editing a record it the exact same as adding a new record but instead of saving it in blank spot in your collectoin, you save it on an already used spot.

Comment: it already works, you provide it as a Produit(). Exactly  the same as if you were to add a new Produit. The only diffrence is that now you will overwright the Produit in your Collection with the same id. Please read clearly what I wrote. If this still isn't the answer to your problem then kindy rephrase your problem.

Comment: I made changes, as you mentioned above but then it doesn't work properly. It is not adding records by making the changes you mentioned !

Comment: I cannot change ArrayList to Map !

Comment: Can you show us where you make the connection between your model and your view? (where you pass the values to the functions, your controller)

Comment: `protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
   throws ServletException, IOException {

  if (req.getParameter("action") != null) {
   op.remove(Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id")));
  } 
  else {
   // Recuprer les information
   String name = req.getParameter("name");
   String address = req.getParameter("address");
   String contactNo = req.getParameter("contactNo");
   String SparePartsService = req.getParameter("SparePartsService");
   op.add(new Produit(1L, name, address, contactNo, SparePartsService));
  }`

Comment: This is where your problem is, you check if action-parameter is null but you never check what the action-parameter's value is if it isn't null. this action-parameter is normally used to check what the user wants to do. wich is also wrong in your jsp page, i'll update my answer

Comment: `if (req.getParameter("action") != null) {
   op.remove(Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id")));
  } else if(req.getParameter("editaction") != null){
   //op.edit(Produit p, String name, address, contactNo, SparePartsService);
   String name = req.getParameter("name");
   String address = req.getParameter("address");
   String contactNo = req.getParameter("contactNo");
   String SparePartsService = req.getParameter("SparePartsService");
   op.remove(Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id")));
   op.add(new Produit(1L, name, address, contactNo, SparePartsService));
      
  }`

Comment: Now it is adding new values and removing old values but the problem is that the new values are null ????

Comment: Please read more clearly what i wrote. the code you just pasted isn't what i meant.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum to help you with your schoolwork. I gave you more then enough working code. Please put some effort in it aswell.